# What permissions do you need to run jobs via SQL Agent?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, sql-agent-job

I've googled my issue all weekend, but can't seem to solve the problem

So basically, I have a query, when I run it manually in a query window, it works fine and my job executes, resulting in an email being sent.  However, when I set up a schedule, I get the following error:

[image]

If you can't read it, the error message says,

"The job failed.  The job was invoked by Schedule 9.  The last step to run was step 1."

Then underneath it says,

"Executed as user 'adminName(not sa)'.  Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259 (SQLSTATE 42000) (Error 22050). The step failed"

So I log in with user sa, and apparently this user needs to have SQL Agent permissions in the msdb database.  According to this screenshot, sa is the owner:

[image]

So since sa is the owner, it would mean it has all the SQL Agent related permissions, right?  Furthermore, the code I'm using executes from the CompanyDB, so I think perhaps this may be the issue.  If I look at properties, under sa, I get this window:

[image]

So the CompanyDB is unchecked for user sa, so in order to allow sa to query CompanyDB in SQL Agent, what permissions would it need?  I'm assuming this is the issue, but I'm not really sure, I can't seem to figure it out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the job do?

Comment: Email a query result

Comment: how did you setup the emailing?

Comment: It's just a query result emailed to myself using Microsoft's sp_send_dbmail stored proc.  Work fine when I execute the code manually, inside SQL Agent however, it fails

Comment: in the sql agent job.. did you setup to execute as `sa` or another user?

Comment: Which user you configured in SQL Agent Service?  Does that user have access to run the job?  User with SQLAgentOperatorRole on MSDB can run the job and other DB permissions needed based on the script you are running..  And What user configured as Job owner?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs should have dbAdmin permissions.  That being said, it depends on whether you wrote to the db, update, or just send the email.

The better option would be to create a webservice and call it when you want to send the email.